# TkInter crashes on OSX when skimage.io is imported

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, crash, scikit-image

Dead simple to reproduce on OSX 10.10.5

```
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

causes a big stack dump

```
2016-01-22 14:54:54.343 Python[59450:2307564] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f80e456abe0
2016-01-22 14:54:54.344 Python[59450:2307564] An uncaught exception was raised
2016-01-22 14:54:54.344 Python[59450:2307564] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f80e456abe0
2016-01-22 14:54:54.344 Python[59450:2307564] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff887a403c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8836176e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff887a70ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff886ece24 ___forwarding___ + 1028
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff886ec998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tk                                  0x0000000112d91527 TkpInit + 476
    6   Tk                                  0x0000000112d0baca Tk_Init + 1788
    7   _tkinter.cpython-35m-darwin.so      0x0000000112be8d6a Tcl_AppInit + 82
    8   _tkinter.cpython-35m-darwin.so      0x0000000112be431e _tkinter_create + 1112
    9   Python                              0x000000010bb11415 PyCFunction_Call + 273
    10  Python                              0x000000010bb74e17 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22399
    11  Python                              0x000000010bb782a4 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1884
    12  Python                              0x000000010bb6f683 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 78
    13  Python                              0x000000010bafa5f3 function_call + 377
    14  Python                              0x000000010bad8970 PyObject_Call + 97
    15  Python                              0x000000010baeb12c method_call + 140
    16  Python                              0x000000010bad8970 PyObject_Call + 97
    17  Python                              0x000000010bb2345d slot_tp_init + 57
    18  Python                              0x000000010bb207e2 type_call + 171
    19  Python                              0x000000010bad8970 PyObject_Call + 97
    20  Python                              0x000000010bb74b73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21723
    21  Python                              0x000000010bb782a4 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1884
    22  Python                              0x000000010bb6f62f PyEval_EvalCode + 81
    23  Python                              0x000000010bb951b5 run_mod + 58
    24  Python                              0x000000010bb95496 PyRun_FileExFlags + 178
    25  Python                              0x000000010bb94aea PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 469
    26  Python                              0x000000010bba8afe Py_Main + 3342
    27  Python                              0x000000010bacbe27 Python + 7719
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8f4305c9 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
2016-01-22 14:54:54.345 Python[59450:2307564] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f80e456abe0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff887a403c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8836176e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff887a70ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff886ece24 ___forwarding___ + 1028
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff886ec998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tk                                  0x0000000112d91527 TkpInit + 476
    6   Tk                                  0x0000000112d0baca Tk_Init + 1788
    7   _tkinter.cpython-35m-darwin.so      0x0000000112be8d6a Tcl_AppInit + 82
    8   _tkinter.cpython-35m-darwin.so      0x0000000112be431e _tkinter_create + 1112
    9   Python                              0x000000010bb11415 PyCFunction_Call + 273
    10  Python                              0x000000010bb74e17 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22399
    11  Python                              0x000000010bb782a4 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1884
    12  Python                              0x000000010bb6f683 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 78
    13  Python                              0x000000010bafa5f3 function_call + 377
    14  Python                              0x000000010bad8970 PyObject_Call + 97
    15  Python                              0x000000010baeb12c method_call + 140
    16  Python                              0x000000010bad8970 PyObject_Call + 97
    17  Python                              0x000000010bb2345d slot_tp_init + 57
    18  Python                              0x000000010bb207e2 type_call + 171
    19  Python                              0x000000010bad8970 PyObject_Call + 97
    20  Python                              0x000000010bb74b73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21723
    21  Python                              0x000000010bb782a4 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1884
    22  Python                              0x000000010bb6f62f PyEval_EvalCode + 81
    23  Python                              0x000000010bb951b5 run_mod + 58
    24  Python                              0x000000010bb95496 PyRun_FileExFlags + 178
    25  Python                              0x000000010bb94aea PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 469
    26  Python                              0x000000010bba8afe Py_Main + 3342
    27  Python                              0x000000010bacbe27 Python + 7719
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8f4305c9 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
[1]    59450 abort      python3 interface.py
```

Comment: Is there a question here, or are you just making a bug report?

Comment: I posted my solution in the hopes that it might help anyone else who comes across this. I'll also submit a real bug report as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by using the scipy versions of imread and imsave

This works fine.

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
```